# Is it bad practice to store BLOB data in a class property

Tags: php, class, blob

Is it bad practice to store the contents of a PDF file in a class property?

I have a `Cart` class which stores information about a customer's shopping cart. Part of the ordering process is that the customer can upload a commercial invoice. Is it bad practice to put the raw contents of that file in a class property (which is persisted through saving to MySQL)?

The files should be relatively small (at most a couple of hundred KB) and there really will only be 1 instance of the class instantiated at the one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a bad idea. Don't do it.

If you store the pdf as a blob in the object, you'll need the whole pdf in memory. If there are multiple objects (maybe in a different script) you'll all those pdfs in memory. (Regardless of whether those pdfs will be used by your code or not)

You should store the path to the pdf file instead. Note that something like `readfile($user->pdf)` will **not** need the whole pdf in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was a bad idea but needed to hear it from somebody else.